# Send Keypress to Google Slides Slideshow from Program

Tags: python, keypress

I am making a program where when a certain action is detected I want the forward arrow key to be sent as a keypress to a Google slideshow which will move the slideshow forward. I have no idea where to begin with this, and I am wondering if this is even possible as from what I have seen, if I press the forward arrow key and my computer screen is not on Google slides, the Google slideshow will not move forward. In my case, I will have my program running on my screen and I need the keypress to be sent to the Google slideshow even though it is not on my screen.

Comment: Autohotkey might be a better program than python for this.

Comment: I am on Mac and the rest of my program is in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `pyautogui`.
Here's the documentation: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Example:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.press('right') #presses right arrow virtually
```

I don't think forcing it to focus on a certain window is possible, though it would be possible on Windows using pyGetWindow.